# I want to have no break line between 2 form widget (input field and submit button)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a simple form, with only one input and the submit button :

```
{% form_theme form 'form.html.twig' %}

{{ form(form) }}
```

In my form.html.twig :

```
{% block form_row %}
  
        <span class="formLabel">
            {{ form_label(form) }}
        </span>
        <span class="formWidget">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
        </span>
        <span class="formErrors">
            {{ form_errors(form) }}
        </span>
    
{% endblock %}
```

I want to have the input field (first widget) on the same line than the submit button (second widget). I thought the solution will be easy but I did not find it :(

Here is the way the form is created :

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($typeClient , array('attr' => array('novalidate' => 'novalidate')))
        ->add('Label', TextType::class , ['label' => 'Libellé :'])
        ->add('Enregistrer', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Enregistrer' , 'attr' => ['style' => 'inline']])
        ->getForm();
```

As you can see, I can add a CSS style on the button itself, but I need to do it on the  which contains it.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div id="form" novalidate="novalidate">        
    
  
        <span class="formLabel">
                        <label for="form_Label" class="required">Libellé :</label>
        </span>
        <span class="formWidget">
            <input type="text" id="form_Label" name="form[Label]" required="required">
        </span>
        <span class="formErrors">
                    
        </span>
    
<div> <!-- I NEED TO PUT MY DISPLAY:INLINE ON THIS DIV AND NOT ON THE BUTTON -->

<button type="submit" id="form_Enregistrer" name="form[Enregistrer]" style="display:inline">Enregistrer</button></div>

<input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="3e47c8ce601970c13bdb2cfcc9.OTm2qTzQ0rjNHkkaugF1hJgkLLjHlmxj358zVH9sJuc.WHyBhH-Km9r6RCpP_mIMxuscXM-C_l0iqNQeJz0UUItYUfflWZ2wz4ppPg"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just don't use the theme and use {{ form_widget(form.Label) }}{{ form_widget(form.Enregistrer) }}

Comment: OK I fixed it by just adding css on the page : 

<style>

#form div
{
    display:inline;
}

</style> I let the question open, if anyone has a solution to do it with twig or in symfony code